# Should a const member function return a const or non-const?

Tags: constants, d

```
struct Type
{
  auto opBinary(string op)(Type other) const {
    return Type();         // #1 return type is Type
    return typeof(this)(); // #2 return type is const(Type)
  }
}

unittest
{
  Type t1, t2;
  auto t3 = t1 + t2;
}
```

In `t1.opBinary!("+")(t2)`, `t1` becomes a const, while `t2` stays non-const.  Should `opBinary`'s return type be `Type` or `const(Type)`, and why?

`const(T)` is a supertype, so maybe it should return a `const`, but I've hardly seen this in practice.  Things also become rather complicated when dealing with a hierarchy of types and functions that use those types or are used by those types.

Answer (score 4):

Since the return value here is a new object, I'd say make it non-const. Being new, it can be modified safely, so no reason to unnecessarily restrict it with const.

If you were returning a part of the existing object, you'll want to use inout instead of const. inout means the constness of the object will also go to the return value.

```
inout(Type) opBinary(string op)(Type other) inout {
    return whatever;
}
```

Now if you use a const(Type) object, the return will be const as well, and if it is called on a mutable object, the return is also mutable.

Answer (score 1):

*Should return type be T or const(T)?* Any will do.

*Which one is better?* Depends on your intended behavior.

**const** qualifier on opBinary only means that hidden "this" argument is **const**. Nothing more, nothing else. It does not imply anything about the return type. It all boils down to pretty simple choice:

```
struct Type
{
    int a;
    auto opBinary(string op)(Type other) const
           if (op == "+")
    {
        return Type(this.a + other.a);
    }
}

void main()
{
    Type first, second;
    (first + second).a = 42; // Do you want to allow this?
                             // Yes -> return non-const
                             // No -> return const
}
```

If you want to preserve qualifiers of arguments, use either **inout** (see Adams answer) or manual check for qualifiers for more complicated choices.

With either choice remember automatic type deduction:

```
auto third = first + second;
third.a = 42; // Error if returns const

Type fourth = first + second;
fourth.a  = 42; // Fine in both cases, struct was copied
```

In the end it is about you intention as a type designer how class/struct should behave.